# Prolog "Out of local stack" Error

Tags: prolog, failure-slice, transitive-closure

Here is my simple Prolog program:

```
friend(X,Y):-
   knows(X,Y).
friend(X,Z):-
   friend(X,Y),
   friend(Y,Z).

knows(brian,tom).
knows(tom,peter).
```

If I type the following query

```
friend(brian,peter).
```

Prolog will give the following output:

```
?- friend(brian,peter).
true
```

If a further type a semicolon, Prolog will say:

```
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in the second clause. It  should be instead:

```
friend(X,Z):-
   knows(X,Y),
   friend(Y,Z).
```

Otherwise, when you ask Prolog for more solutions, you end up having the `friend/2`predicate recursively calling itself without first establishing a `knows/2`intermediate relation. You can learn more about the bug in your program by tracing the calls to the `friend/2` predicate. Try:

```
?- trace, friend(brian,peter).
```

Answer (score 1):

The understand the source of non-termination in your program it suffices to look at the following failure-slice:

```
friend(X,Y):- false,
   knows(X,Y).
friend(X,Z):- 
   friend(X,Y), false,
   friend(Y,Z).

knows(brian,tom) :- false.
knows(tom,peter) :- false.
```

It is because of `friend(X, Z) :- friend(X, Y), ...` that your program will not terminate. It will produce answers, here and there, but ultimately it will loop. For more, see [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice).